# git: rebase (after merge) gives only conflicts

Tags: git, merge, conflict, rebase

I have the following situation

- created a branch 'dev'
- worked on 'dev'
- worked on 'master'

At some point I want to merge my work from 'dev' into master

```
$> git checkout master
$> git merge dev
```

Thats no problem, but now I would like to continue working in branch 'dev'. However, 'master' has some commits which are not yet in 'dev', so I tried to rebase.

```
$> git checkout dev
$> git rebase master
```

This doesn't work and only gives conflicts. Solving the conflicts doesn't work, because after that there are more conflicts. 
Is there an explanation for this ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit unclear what you want to achieve. At the beginning you wrote:

> At some point I want to merge my work from 'dev' into master

Then you wrote:

> However, 'master' has some commits which are not yet in 'dev', so I tried to rebase.

If you want to get the work from `dev` into `master` you should

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git rebase dev`
3. solve conflicts if needed
4. `git rebase --continue`

Then you can go back to `dev` branch with `git checkout dev`

If you want to do it the other way, just switch the names
I personally think that running `git rebase --continue` is the key to your problem.

PS: Instead of rebasing, try to consider running a `git merge` in this case.

Comment: thnx for the reply. I did first merged 'dev' into 'master' and afterwards I tried to rebase 'dev' (check my question because I've updated it)

Comment: @jthill if you look [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) at the 3rd picture, they did `git checkout master; git rebase dev`, in this case `their experiment = our master; their master = our dev`, the work from their master (C4) is part of their experiment branch, what I want to say is that after rebasing, you can be sure that the work from what you rebase to is in included in our HEAD

Comment: What was I thinking.  Of course it will. Doing a trivial edit to take back the downvote, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable way to get the changes from master back into dev after you have merged dev into master is by **merging** master into dev, not rebasing dev on top of master.

Rebasing is usually only used on branches that haven't been merged into anything yet.